# Replace values with NaN

Tags: python, replace, nan

I have a list of indices, as follows

```html
indeces_to_replace= [3,5,6]
```

and I would like to replace all the values in these indices(rows) in my dataset with NaN values. Can someone guide me?

The dataset looks like that:

```html
i     v1     v2       v3
0      3     6         8
1      5     7         10
2      12    11        8
3      14    13        3
4      12    2         4 
5      12    13        32
6      11    9         11
7      9     8         7
```

So basically I would like to replace indices 3,5,6 with NaN entirely.

Comment: Show us how your dataset looks like? Have you tried anything yourself to achieve this @AlexDavies ?

Comment: I updated the question to answer your first question. what I tried is the follwoing `df=df.replace(indices_to_replace, np.nan)` but it didn't work @DeveshKumarSingh

Answer (score 0):

You can use **iloc** to select a row, then replace values. As an example:

```
data = {'v1': [3,5,12], 'v2': [6,7,11], 'v3':[8,10,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

   v1  v2  v3
0   3   6   8
1   5   7  10
2  12  11   8
```

Results

```
df.iloc[1] = np.nan

     v1    v2   v3
0   3.0   6.0  8.0
1   NaN   NaN  NaN
2  12.0  11.0  8.0
```

Edit

```
df.iloc[:, 1:] = np.nan

   v1  v2  v3
0   3 NaN NaN
1   5 NaN NaN
2  12 NaN NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, Can you please modify the code where you don't delete the entire row, For example: for the dataset I had. I would like to keep v1 and replace v2 and v3 with nan

Answer (score 0):

Pass a `list` to `iloc` and assign to `np.nan`:

```
df.iloc[[3, 5, 6]] = np.nan
```

If you only want to modify the `v2` and `v3` columns, use `loc`:

```
df.loc[[3, 5, 6], ['v2', 'v3']] = np.nan
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @gmds. Can you please modify the code where you don't delete the entire row, For example: for the dataset I had. I would like to keep v1 and replace v2 and v3 with nan